# Can I have different index's crawlers with the same root item and database?

Tags: indexing

In a theoretical scenario on which I have **two different indexes** (different types and behaviors) which will be **crawling the same root `/Sitecore/Content`**, can this cause weird behaviors or some kind of conflict?

I can think of any, but I'd like to hear from the community if someone knows or experienced something in the past.

Comment: Will cause no issues. Many of Sitecore's 10 or so indexes are crawling the same data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no harm in doing this.

`sitecore_master_index` root is set to `/sitecore` and all the other indexes which operates on `master` database have their roots set to one of the `/sitecore` item descendants. It works just fine.

You can create another index with `/sitecore` as a root without any issues.

I can imagine having a bucket with different type of items in it and having multiple indexes with their root set to the bucket root, one of the indexing only items which use templateA and another indexing only another template.

Question is: **"is it worth to maintain 2 indexes instead of having 1 index and then getting what you want from the index using more specific queries?"**. But the answer is **"it depends"** and this may a very good solution in your scenario.